# An Application interfaced with mobile

Tags: oracle, java-me, frontend

I have an idea to design an application which is interfaced with a mobile. The application has to note down each and every transactions happening in the mobile like making a note of all incoming messages and store appropriate information in the application's database to perform manipulations. Is this possible ? Can you suggest me an appropriate technologies for the same.

Answer (score 0):

in j2me for blackberry [call logs apis](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Retrieve_call_history_565563_11.jsp) are there but not for another devices.

like for nokia you have to use symbian c++.

Answer (score 0):

You included an Oracle tag but didn't say why.  I am guessing your core application has an Oracle database.

If you are looking for an embedded database for your mobile app which can exchange data with the main DB then have a look at [Oracle Lite](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/lite/index.html).  This is a Java product which runs on the main mobile platforms (Windows 2003/XP/Vista, Windows Mobile and Pocket PC, Linux, embedded Linux and the Symbian OS but not - yet - the iPhone).

The Oracle Lite model is designed for primarily offline working, with sporadic data refreshes (using Oracle's Replication functionality).  The alternative model, online working using 3G data (or WiFi or whatever) is more complicated.  This is because the implications for losing a signal midway through a database transaction are considerably more significant than when we are surfing Boing Boing.  Unfortunately you are not entirely clear in your question as to which approach you want to take.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will brief you about my idea. I will have an application in my computer which will be interfaced with the mobile. That application will have to process the messages that reach the inbox of the mobile. Processing and storing will be the function of this application. So for this purpose I need a DB (oracle) and J2ME as this involves mobile.